# Mercurial: how to merge changes to a file that's renamed in the other branch?

Tags: mercurial, merge, rename

I have a Mercurial repository with four branches in it. One is the "common" branch, the other three are "specific" branches which consist of some cosmetic changes applied to the common branch. One of those cosmetic changes consisted of renaming some files.

So the common branch has "file.txt", and the first specific branch has "file-01.txt" which is *the same file, used for the same purpose* but has a different name and slightly different contents. It was renamed to file-01.txt on the specific branch, and "hg log -f file-01.txt" correctly shows the history going back to before the rename.

When I make a change to file.txt on the common branch, I need to be able to merge that change into file-01.txt on the specific branch. But Mercurial doesn't understand that the files are the same. It tells me:

> remote changed file.txt which local deleted
>
> use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted?

If I pick "c" then I get a new file.txt containing exactly what's in the common branch's version. If I pick "d" then the change isn't merged at all.

What can I do to get this right?

---

EDIT: I can make it work correctly in a fresh test repository, but not my actual repo. Here's what I get (note that rev 118 is on the specific branch, just before the original rename, so I'm going through the rename process again to illustrate):

> C:\...> hg update -C 118
>
> 0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
>
> C:\...> hg merge default
>
> merging file.txt
> merging anotherfile.txt
> 0 files updated, 2 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
> (branch merge, don't forget to commit)

So it works without the rename. But if I rename, it fails:

> C:\...> hg update -C 118
>
> 2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files resolved
>
> C:\...> hg rename file.txt file-01.txt
> C:\...> hg commit -m "renamed"
>
> created new head
>
> C:\...> hg merge default
>
> remote changed file.txt which local deleted
> use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted?

---

EDIT 2: Here's what I get at that last step from `hg merge --debug default`:

> searching for copies back to rev 115
> unmatched files in local:
> file-01.txt
> all copies found (* = to merge, ! = divergent):
> file-01.txt -> file.txt
>
> checking for directory renames
> resolving manifests
> overwrite None partial False
> ancestor 9d979018c2df local f842fdbc252b+ remote 05fc75e480da
> anotherfile.txt: versions differ -> m
> remote changed file.txt which local deleted
> use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted?

Comment: This is strange since Mercurial normally knows how to merge changes into the renamed file. Here is a worked example that you can try to verify it: http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/tasks.html#merging-default-into-a-branch I don't know what happened in your case, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up tracking the problem down to one particular revision in the history: I could merge across the rename as long as that revision wasn't involved. Still not sure what went wrong with that revision, but I redid the changes and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you handled the rename in the branch.  From the looks of it you (or your GUI) did a 'remove' on the old name, file.txt, and then did an add of a copy of that file named file-01.txt.

When you do it that way, mercurial has no idea they're linked.  If, however, you had, in the branch, used the command:

```
hg rename file.txt file-01.txt
```

then rather than the message you're seeing the changes from file.txt would be applied to file-01.txt.  However, without your help mercurial can't know they're linked.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but he says `hg log -f file-01.txt` correctly follows the history back through the *rename*... that makes me believe he did rename it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing it was renamed in file browser GUI and then got the add/remove from an IDE.  If I'm wrong then it's definitely something deeper, but my guess is 'hg rename' wasn't used.  Admittedly it's a hunch.

Comment: IIRC I used the Rename feature in TortoiseHg -- it would've been either that or the Guess Renames feature. I'll play around to see if that works differently from `hg rename`

Comment: See the edited question - it works if I create a fresh test repo to play around with, but I get the same error in my actual repo whether I use `hg rename` or TortoiseHg's Rename feature. The log definitely shows the file being copied to the new name and deleted under the old name (which is how Hg represents renames, right?). I can't see any notable differences in the logs between the repo where this works and the one where it fails.

Comment: In your original repo when you do a 'hg log -p --git' on the changeset where the rename happened does it say "renamed" or does it show as a delete and an add?

Comment: It shows "rename from file.txt" followed by "rename to file-01.txt".

Comment: BTW, I've been redacting the file names - the file in question is actually in a subdirectory, if that matters. It hasn't been moved in or out, just renamed within the directory.

Comment: Hrm, then my guess was wrong.  It sounds like you did it right to begin with.  I'd delete this answer, but it has some stuff in the comments that might help others come up with a good one.